# Changing Workbook Local

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that is shared with coworkers overseas. We ran into an issue recently. The user would manually enter a date into a cell. Ex. 04/18/2019 (April 18th 2019 - mm/dd/yyyy). In Canada, the workbook would default to US en local and would read it as April 18th 2019 - mm/dd/yyyy. However, my coworkers in London would have it read as dd/mm/yyyy, which in the case of this example, does not exist.

I looked around and found that there is a method to change the local upon opening the file from a different file.

```
 workbook = workbooks.Open(filename, Local:= false)
```

Is there a method to change the local from within the workbook or a way to hardcode the local to be US en?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately excel uses your OS Region Language  , the only possibility is to hard code functions to format date with Format()  and FormatDateTime().

-Maybe with API's you can change the OS Lenguague (dont do that)

-Maybe your coworkers can change theis Lenguague OS just to use the system... I dont know what is better for you.

Sorry if i not helped you

Comment: Don't be sorry, this is the answer! And nicely thorough, too - upvoted, keep 'em coming!

Comment: Thanks for the info! At least now I know there is no point of continuing to search for something that doesn't exist.